# Decorators in typescript throws compilation error

Tags: typescript, decorator

I am trying to test decorators in typescript but when I compile the ts code the I get error

```
error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.

error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
```

I have decorator config in tsconfig.json correctly

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target"                  : "ES5",
      "experimentalDecorators"  : true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata"   : true
  }
}
```

I have tried all things found on internet to fix this but the error is not going

tsc version 3.4.2

As per one post issue is because on compilation os ts code when decorator is called, it is called with one less argument

```
__decorate([
        f()
    ], C.prototype, "ffolow");
```

and class that is using decorator is

```
class C {

  @f()
  ffolow() {
    console.log("FF called")
  }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [ask] A Good Question.  If I can't reproduce your problem, I'm not likely to be able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your decorator is defined. Assuming it is just a 'regular' decorator (not a decorator factory), then you should apply it without parentheses:

```
function f(target: any, propertyName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
  //
}

class C {

  @f
  ffolow() {
    console.log("FF called")
  }

}
```